# Android firebase notification not work

Tags: android, firebase, notifications, firebase-cloud-messaging

I want to implement the Firebase-Messaging plugin into my Android-App.
I think I followed all the necessary steps. But it doesn't work.

***build app :module***

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion "26.0.0"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.dev.app"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }

    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE' // will not include NOTICE file
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE' // will not include LICENSE file
        // as noted by @Vishnuvathsan you may also need to include
        // variations on the file name. It depends on your dependencies.
        // Some other common variations on notice and license file names
        exclude 'META-INF/notice'
        exclude 'META-INF/notice.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/license'
        exclude 'META-INF/license.txt'
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })



    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.android.volley:volley:1.0.0'
    compile 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:2.5.3'
    compile 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-annotations:2.5.3'
    compile 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:2.5.3'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:11.0.2'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:11.0.2'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:11.0.2'
}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

***build app :project***

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.3'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.1.0'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

***AndroidManifest***

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.dev.app">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE"/>

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/icon"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/icon"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:configChanges="orientation"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">

        </activity>





        <service android:name=".MyFirebaseMessagingService"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </service>
        <service android:name=".FirebaseIDService">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.firebase.INSTANCE_ID_EVENT"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </service>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

***FirebaseIDService***

```
public class FirebaseIDService extends FirebaseInstanceIdService {
    private static final String TAG = "FirebaseIDService";

    @Override
    public void onTokenRefresh() {
        // Get updated InstanceID token.
        String refreshedToken = FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getToken();
        Log.d(TAG, "Refreshed token: " + refreshedToken);

        // TODO: Implement this method to send any registration to your app's servers.
        sendRegistrationToServer(refreshedToken);
    }

    /**
     * Persist token to third-party servers.
     *
     * Modify this method to associate the user's FCM InstanceID token with any server-side account
     * maintained by your application.
     *
     * @param token The new token.
     */
    private void sendRegistrationToServer(String token) {
        // Add custom implementation, as needed.
    }
}
```

***MyFirebaseMessagingService***

```
public class MyFirebaseMessagingService extends FirebaseMessagingService {
    private static final String TAG = "FCM Service";
    @Override
    public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
        // TODO: Handle FCM messages here.
        // If the application is in the foreground handle both data and notification messages here.
        // Also if you intend on generating your own notifications as a result of a received FCM
        // message, here is where that should be initiated.
        Log.d(TAG, "From: " + remoteMessage.getFrom());
        Log.d(TAG, "Notification Message Body: " + remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody());
    }
}
```

***i have downloaded google-services.json***
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pfEHm.png)

And send message from firebase console 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pfEHm.png)

But i don't get any notifications.

Comment: your app is open or in background?

Comment: my app is open  .

Comment: did you check your log, means print or not?

Comment: So to clarify if is realy not working try close app and send notification, if not shows you have an problem but if show you dont have problem, you only need to make notification inside **onMessageReceived**

Comment: i closed the app and i sent notification and i recieved it. i will make notification inside now

Comment: Just in case, make sure to test it on real device with latest play store service and in Emulator make sure to use Google API which include play store service.